# Why does this 120 GB insert grow the log by over 780 GB?

Tags: sql-server

A table `[tbl_old]` has about 3 billion rows and about 120 GB for disk space, and then created a `[tbl_new]` with the same schema (actually, just dumped the script of `[tbl_old]`, then rename the table name to `[tbl_new]`, then create it).

But when running this SQL script:

```
insert [tbl_new] 
   select * from [tbl_old]
```

After the transaction log file used up about 780 GB and hung.

My questions are:

- Is it reasonable for just such inserting script for about 120 GB, more than 780 GB transaction log is not enough?
- What is in the log file?

Background:

1. the DB is in simple recovery mode, and no index on these `[tbl_old]` and `[tbl_new]`
2. SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on Window Server 2008 64bit.
3. And Intel Xeon CPU E5645 @2.4GHz (2 processors), 24 CPUs, 64 GB memory

Comment: What are the growth settings for that log file?

Answer (score 7):

The log contains an exact description of every inserted record. That is at least 120GB, but must be multiplied by some factor for additional info. 1.5x is a good estimate => ~180Gb. Every record must reserve in the log space for compensation on rollback. 1:1 ratio between do and undo is a good estimate => ~360Gb. Now 780Gb is more than double this estimate. There could be explanations for such high size, like any other concurrent activity in the DB. You can use [`fn_dblog`](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) to investigate how exactly the log is used, if you must know.

Remember that `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...` is an [operation that can be minimally logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx) but `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ...` is actually **not**, unless the special trace flag 610 is used, see [Minimal Logging changes in SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/minimal-logging-changes-in-sql-server-2008-part-2) for details on *all* requirements to achieve minimally logging with `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using TABLOCK hint on the target table. It will probably go into minimally-logged mode and finish quicker, using far less log space as well ;-)

Comment: Good point made by Remus - no index was mentioned, so I assumed it is inserting into a heap.
If there is a clustered index (and the insertion is in clustered index order) then you do need flag 610.